# Reading depth buffer using OpenGLES3

Tags: opengl-es, depth-buffer, opengl-es-3.0, glreadpixels

In **OpenGL** I am able to read the z-buffer values, using `glReadPixels`, like so:

```
glReadPixels(scrx, scry, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);
```

If I do the same in **OpenGL ES 3.2** I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

Checking the specification, I see that OpenGL [allows](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, but OpenGLES3 [does not](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/).

As a work-around, I copied the fragment depth to the alpha value in the colour buffer using this GLSL:

```
#version 320 es
...
outCol = vec4(psCol.rgb, gl_FragCoord.z);
```

After doing glReadPixels() on the `GL_RGBA` part of the framebuffer, I use `rgba[3]/255.0` as the depth value.

Although this works, the 8-bit precision on the alpha value is insufficient for my purpose of picking what is under the mouse cursor.

Is there a way to get Z values from the framebuffer in OpenGL ES3?

Answer (score 1):

There is an OpenGL ES Extension [NV_read_depth](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_read_depth_stencil.txt) which allows reading from the depth buffer by `glReadPixels`. The extension is written against the OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification, but is still not standard in OpenGL ES 3.2.

Get a set of the OpenGL es extension names by:

```cpp
std::set<std::string> ogl_es_extensins;
GLint no_of_extensions = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &no_of_extensions);
for ( int i = 0; i < no_of_extensions; ++i )
{
    std::string ext_name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, i));
    ogl_es_extensins.insert(ext_name);
}
```

Note, you can either try to read the depth buffer (*NV_read_depth*) or the depth and stencil buffer (*NV_read_depth_stencil*);